# Dimensions of subspaces and generating sets.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Say I have two subspaces $U$, $V$ of some finite-dimensional vector space with generating sets $A$ and $B$.

I can't seem to find a nice and concise proof of the following (also implying I'm not even sure it is true):

If and only if none of the elements in $B$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $A$ and vice versa, then $dim(U+V)=dim(U)+dim(V)$.

From a different perspective, I could also ask: If I want to check if $U\cap V=\{0\}$, is it sufficient to check if I can make vectors in $B$ with vectors in $A$ and the other way around?

I would be happy if someone could help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $v\in U\cap V$. Then $v$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $V$ and also as a linear combination of elements of $U$. By hypothesis, this is only possible for $v=0$.